# Why is a return statement in a switch statement treated as returning from the function, instead of returning from the switch?

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, return, g++

I'm learning `c++`. I tried to compile this with `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    switch(int x = 2)
    {
        case 2:
            std::cout << "2";
            return;
        default:
            std::cout << "other";
            return;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, in this case, the compiler produces this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:13: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
   10 |             return;
      |             ^~~~~~
main.cpp:13:13: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
   13 |             return;
      |             ^~~~~~
```

So, I tried to use `-fpermissive` option, as in error message: `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -fpermissive`. Now, the compiler produces warnings, and the program is compiled successfully:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:13: warning: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
   10 |             return;
      |             ^~~~~~
main.cpp:13:13: warning: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'int' [-fpermissive]
   13 |             return;
      |             ^~~~~~
```

As I understood, this behavior is because the compiler determines `return` statement in switch, as signal to leave `main` function, but it has `int` type, and need a returning value in this case.
But why it rather doesn't determine it as signal to leave from switch?

I use GNU GCC, and Windows 10.

Comment: `return` really means leaving the function. In the switch you should use `break` instead.

Comment: If you want to break from a switch-case, use `break`

Comment: "_So, I tried to use -fpermissive option, as in error message_": Never do that. The `-fpermissive` flag is intended to tell the compiler to ignore anything fishy and that you know for sure what you are doing, which you clearly as a beginner don't. Even if one knows what they are doing, there is no good reason to use that flag except on very old code that is written in ways that are not compatible with the current standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this behavior is because the compiler determines return statement in switch, as signal to leave main function, but it has int type, and need a returning value in this case.

Your understanding is correct.

> But why it rather doesn't determine it as signal to leave from switch?

Because `return` is specified to return from the function in which the statement appears.

> 8.7.4. The `return` statement `[stmt.return]`
>
> 1. A function returns to its caller by the return statement.

To only leave the closest `switch`, you can use `break` statement:

> 8.7.2 The `break` statement `[stmt.break]`
>
> 1. A `break` statement shall be enclosed by (8.1) an iteration-statement (8.6) or a `switch` statement (8.5.3). The `break` statement causes termination of the smallest such enclosing statement; control passes to the statement following the terminated statement, if any.

There are other options for just leaving the `switch`, like using `goto` or throwing exceptions, but the `break` statement is what's most commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

I need to use `break` instead of `return`:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    switch(int x = 2)
    {
        case 2:
            std::cout << "2";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "other";
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```